# Can not multiply two lists

Tags: python, string, list

Apologies as I am new to python. I have extracted 2 lists of numbers from a text file using regular expressions but now I would like to multiply both lists. However, I just get a value of `{}`

```
listd = {}
listn = {}

numerator = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
denominator = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']

[numerator*denominator for numerator,denominator in zip(listn,listd)]
```

I get an error saying the following when I print out the result of listd or listn:

`{}`

Answer (score 4):

`listd` and `lstn` are declared as empty dicts (`{}`)

`numerator` and `denominator` are lists, they're hidden by your list contraption (same name, lower scope variable)

`[int(n)*int(d) for n,d in zip(numerator,denominator)]` is probably what you're looking for

Not really clear what you want to do though...

*EDIT*

- added int conversion
- {} are empty dicts, not sets

FTR:

- {1,2,3} = set([1,2,3])
- {1:2} => dict
- {} => dict

Comment: Don't forget that the inputs are strings - OP will have to turn them into integers with `int()` first.

Comment: Nothing a quick little map cant fix: `[n*d for n,d in zip(map(int, numerator),map(int,denominator))]`

Comment: instead of mapping both list, I used the int in the actual operation, seems easier to understand for people not adept in functional programming IMHO

Comment: Just a note, `{}` is an empty `dict` and not an empty `set`.

Comment: @Bruce yeah i suppose you're right. I was timing the two because... why not? 

>>> %timeit [int(n)*int(d) for n,d in zip(numerator,denominator)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 µs per loop

>>> %timeit [n*d for n,d in zip(map(int, numerator),map(int,denominator))]
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.4 µs per loop

I expected it to be slower by a lot. Its not. -- The more you know.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have lists of strings and not numbers so you will need to convert them.

You are also multiplying elements in `listd` and `listn` which are empty dictionaries, you don't even need these variables.

```
numerator = [int(n) for n in numerator]
denominator = [int(d) for d in denominator]
multiplied_list = [n*d for n,d in zip(numerator ,denominator)]
```